# How to distinguish different cracks/enriched regions in Abaqus from UDMGINI subroutine?

Tags: fortran, abaqus

I want to use different failure criteria for two or more separate enriched regions in one model. The regions are always in different instances made from different materials. I've tried to get instances' names to distinguish them (see the code below), but this works very unstable - I often receive error flag in JRCD variable. Is there any way to get the current material name/element set/crack name in UDMGINI? Thanks

```
<...>
CHARACTER*80 CPNAME
INTEGER IERROR
<...>
CALL GETPARTINFO(NOEL, 1, CPNAME, LOCNUM, JRCD)
IERROR = IERROR + JRCD
<...>
IF (CPNAME.EQ.'INSTANCE_NAME_1') THEN
<calculation of failure criterion 1>
ELSEIF (CPNAME.EQ.'INSTANCE_NAME_2') THEN
<calculation of failure criterion 2>
END IF
IF (IERROR.NE.ZERO) THEN
 WRITE(6,*) 'REQUEST ERROR IN UDMGINI FOR ELEMENT NUMBER ',
+ NOEL,'INTEGRATION POINT NUMBER ', NPT, ' (INSTANCE NAME)'
END IF
<...>
```

Comment: I suspect this is better asked in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ - it's about Abaqus really, not programming

Comment: As a workaround I found such an option: 1) get numbers of elements by addition of *Preprint 2) use something like IF (NOEL >= 1 .AND. NOEL <= 15090) THEN... instead of CPNAME condition